# func with params of not fixed type

Tags: go

Is it possible in `GoLang`:

```
func funcWithDynamicTypeArgs(param notFixedType) 
{

}
```

I want `param` let be `int` and `string` and `map` and any type. 
In other words: is it possible in `Go` to declare and use `function` with dynamic type arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
func function(param interface{}) {
}
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Interface types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)
>
> All types implement the empty interface:
>
> ```
> interface{}
> ```
>
> [Type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)
>
> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.

---

See [package fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) which uses [package reflect](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) to handle arguments of any type. For example,

> [func Print](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Print)
>
> ```
> func Print(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> Print formats using the default formats for its operands and writes to
>   standard output. Spaces are added between operands when neither is a
>   string. It returns the number of bytes written and any write error
>   encountered.

Comment: Nitpicking: `param` is not of "dynamic type" it has a static type of `interface {}`. It just happens that some static types in Go (the interface) contain an additional dynamic type.